# What is the Possible Approach to read a .property file and populate the map in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a property file local.properties

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

how can i read this property file in javascript and create a map of this key value pair .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function(){
        //reading of file 
     }
</script>
```

Thanks .

Comment: You'd have an easier time parsing the file using a server-side language then making it available to the javascript as a javascript object or json.

Comment: can you please tell me any approach for client side ?

Comment: @user3718420 you can't access this client-side. You need to put the file in a string of text at the very least on the html document.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking your property file follow this struture and the page doesn't access the file directly (because javascript can't access disk directly), you can do something like...

```js
var propertFileStr = "key1=value1 key2=value2";
var strVet = propertFileStr.split(" ");
var obj = {};
strVet.forEach(function(item){
    obj[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1];
});
console.log(obj);
```

In this example, `propertFileStr` is completed with base in uploaded file and each property divided by a space, and then it's possible the catch each property and then convert it to key value object.

Comment: Thanks , i will try this approach .